# Generate array with random numbers from source array (whose length is smaller than destination array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using javascript and here is the problem statement

```
const sourceArray = [3, 6, 9]

const elementsToGenerate = 10
```

expected output is random numbers from sourceArray till the length of the output array is 10 and should have at least 1 of each element from sourceArray and should be spread almost evenly

example output 1 [3,9,6,6,3,9,6,3,3,9]

example output 2 [9,6,3,9,6,9,3,9,3,6]

Comment: This isn't chatGPT. What attempt have you made?

Comment: What is *"spread **almost** evenly"*? What is the formula you have in mind to say that something is spread almost evenly or is not?

Comment: Let's say the output has to have two 1s in an array of length 5. Is `1***1` just as evenly spread as `*1*1*`? Or is only one of those considered to be an even spread? And is `*1*1*` just as evenly spread as `**1*1`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan calm down, no need to get all charged up. I'm also solving at the same time and have an inefficient solution with lots of if conditions. wanted to see if someone can help me out with better.

Comment: @trincot spread evenly if the source array has [2,5] then the results should be even 5x2 and 5x5. but if the source array has 3 elements [3,6,9] then the result array should contain 3 or 4 elements of 3, 3 or 4 elements of 6, and 3 or 4 elements of 9. as it cannot have 3x3, 3x6, 3x9 cause it will have room for 1 more repetition to have length of 10

Comment: I think I got a working solution. phew! will optimize it a bit more and post it unless some else posts better solution in couple of hour

Comment: I think I have a solution. You might miss it because it was an earlier solution that I undeleted, so I've sent this msg so you are notified

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all unique elements from the source array exist in the output, so start with the unique elements from the source array.

Then, add as many random values from the source array as required to reach the target number.

Calculate the frequency of each unique number in the array. For each unique number, determine the indices it should be at in the target array when spread out evenly.

There will be clashes where more than one number wants to be in a certain position, but that's ok - we can just allow one to follow the other. We sprinkle in Number.EPSILON, which is a tiny number, in order to prevent the index sort process from clumping the results when more than one value wants to be at the same index.

```js
const src = [3, 6, 9]

const len = 20

let arr = [...new Set(src)]
while(arr.length<len) arr.push(src[src.length*Math.random()|0])

function spreadEvenly(arr) {
  const freq = arr.reduce((a,c)=>(a[c]??=0,a[c]++,a),{})
  return Object.entries(freq)
    .sort(([,a],[,b])=>b-a)
    .flatMap(([k,v],j)=>
      Array(v).fill(0).map((_,i)=>[k,j*Number.EPSILON+i*arr.length/v])
    ).sort(([,a],[,b])=>a-b).map(([i])=>+i)
}

console.log(...spreadEvenly(arr))
```

Comment: how about "should be spread almost evenly"?

Answer (score -1):

> should have at least 1 of each element from sourceArray and should be spread almost evenly

To match the above requirements I suggest creating a pseudorandom array where the number of elements is spread evenly

1. Repeat the array so you have equal number of elements: `[3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9]`
2. Fill in the missing items by choosing items from the source array
3. Shuffle

```js
const sourceArray = [3, 6, 9]

const elementsToGenerate = 10

// how many source arrays fit into elementsToGenerate
const ratio = Math.floor(elementsToGenerate / sourceArray.length)

// repeated sourceArray -> [3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9]
const longSourceArray = [...Array(ratio)].map(() => sourceArray).flat()

// longSourceArray has only 9 elements, but we need 10, we miss 1 element
const missing = elementsToGenerate - longSourceArray.length

// how many elements should be removed from sourceArray to match elementsToGenerate
const diff = sourceArray.length - missing

// copy the array
const copy = [...sourceArray]

// remove excesive elements
for (let i = 0; i < diff; i += 1) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length)
  copy.splice(index, 1)
}

// final array longSourceArray and one random item from sourceArray
const finalArray = [...longSourceArray, ...copy]

// shuffle
for (let i = 0; i < finalArray.length - 2; i += 1) {
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (finalArray.length - i) + i)
  const temp = finalArray[i]
  finalArray[i] = finalArray[j]
  finalArray[j] = temp
}

console.log(finalArray)
```

Comment: how about "should be spread almost evenly"?

Comment: @gog maybe I misunderstood this part. I thought OP wants an almost equal number of each element, not an equal spread of values in the array. For the given input my solution yield at least 3 of each item and then add one item at random